# Extract only video from file using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I have an mp4 file named "input.mp4" and I need to extract only the video stream into another mp4 file, without re-encoding. How can I do that? I found a way to extract the audio stream but I can't find a way to extract the video.

This is how I extract the audio stream:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinFF\ffmpeg.exe" -i input.mp4 -vn -acodec copy output.aac

Comment: `-an -vcodec copy`

Comment: @TomYan - thanks! I guess I am not the only one looking for this, can you add it as an answer? You deserve more points